# How to update stripe's legal_entity.verification.document?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

How to update  stripe's legal_entity.verification.document with PHP ?

Is it a file to upload to stripe.

Comment: Is it a document number or a file to upload?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`legal_entity[verification][document]`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_object-legal_entity-verification-document) attribute should be set to a [file upload](https://stripe.com/docs/api#file_upload_object)'s ID.

[This part](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#uploading-a-file) of the documentation explains how to upload a file using Stripe's API, and [this part](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#attaching-the-file) explains how to attach the uploaded file to a managed account.

Comment: Updated URL for [file upload](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#legal-entity).

Answer (score 1):

You need to first pass the file to your server in  multipart/form-data format. Get the path and add the path in Stripe FileUpload function.

You can even test the file upload by keeping the file manually in server directory and pass the file path to the function.
Below is the sample.

```
  $account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve('acct_xxxxxxxxxxx');
  $uploadedFile = \Stripe\FileUpload::create(
                   array("purpose" => "identity_document",
                         "file" => fopen('file.png', 'r') 
        )
    );
```

You will get a success upload response with file id and this id you need to pass in legal_entity.verification.document like :

```
 $account->legal_entity->verification->document = $uploadedFile->id;
 $account->save();
```